# Solving $x\sqrt{2}=1-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$ of the equation,

$$x\sqrt{2}=1-x$$

According to the solution, $x$ is supposed to be $\sqrt{2}-1$. The solutions to this test have proven wrong from case to case, so I wonder ...

If you solve it like this: $x\sqrt{2}+x = 1$ and pull out $x$ to get $x(\sqrt{2}+1) = 1$. Then, dividing by $\sqrt{2}+1$, we get

$$x=\frac1{\sqrt{2}+1}$$

right?

Comment: The source is incorrect; your answer is correct.

Comment: Are those answers different?

Comment: $\frac 1{\sqrt 2 +1} =  \sqrt 2 -1$ so both you and the book are correct.

Comment: Your method is the correct way and I presume the way the book wanted you to do it.  But if you remove the radical from the denominator you can express it as the book did.

Answer (score 5):

The convention is, if the answer contains radicals in the denominator, they should be rationalized. Thus,

$$x=\frac1{\sqrt{2}+1}
=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}-1)}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{(\sqrt{2})^2-1}=\sqrt{2}-1$$

Answer (score 3):

$\frac 1{\sqrt 2 + 1}=\frac 1{\sqrt 2+1}\frac {\sqrt 2 -1}{\sqrt 2 -1} = \frac {\sqrt 2 -1}{\sqrt 2^2 + \sqrt 2 - \sqrt 2 - 1} = \frac {\sqrt 2 -1}{2-1} =\frac {\sqrt 2-1}1 = \sqrt 2 -1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is correct $x=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{(1+\sqrt{2})(1-\sqrt{2})}=\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{(1-2)}=\sqrt{2}-1$

Answer (score 1):

Your work seems right. But let's check the given solution:

$$(\sqrt2-1)\sqrt2 =2-\sqrt2=1-(\sqrt2-1)$$

It checks out!

But a linear equation of this form can have only one solution. We conclude that the two solutions must be equivalent. In fact,

$$ \frac1{\sqrt2+1} = \frac1{\sqrt2+1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt2-1}{\sqrt2-1} = \frac{\sqrt2-1}{2-1}=\sqrt2-1 $$